# Determing incorrect set theory statements

Tags: elementary-set-theory

[image]

For the first part:

I think 4. and 5. are meaningless. 4. because an event is a set of outcomes, and squaring an outcome in general is meaningless (unless say we have the outcome of rolling a die, we can square that?)

5. I am not sure what is meant by an infinite event? Can we have an infinite set of outcomes?

For the second part of the question:

I think 3. and 5. are incorrect. We can have an event which has no outcomes, e.g. the empty set. I think 5. is false because we can have outcomes which just have not been defined in any event.

Could someone check my reasoning?

Comment: For your first list, number 4 is definitely meaningless, but for your other choice, consider picking number $n$ from $\mathbb{N}$. The event that $n$ is even would be an event that has an infinite number of outcomes. The only other one that could be construed as meaningless is #2. Complements are always taken relative to the sample space, so it doesn't make sense to talk about the complement of the sample space (although it could be construed to be the empty set, but this is why definitions matter!)

Comment: @LaarsHelenius: I disagree about #2. The entire sample space is subset of itself. So its complement is a meaningful concept. And it happens to be the empty set, as you said yourself.

Answer (score 0):

First question. I agree that 4 is meaningless. The other one is 6. Why? Because events are sets, and sets by definition are **unordered** collections of elements. (At first, statement 5 also sounded suspicious to me; but after giving it a little more thought, I think they mean a subset with infinitely many elements, i.e. of infinite cardinality, which is meaningful.)

Second question. I agree that 3 is false. The other one is 4, I think. There's a subtle difference between an *element* and a *set consisting of a single element*. Technically speaking, they are not the same thing: $x\neq\{x\}$, as they are objects of different kinds, so to speak.